# table-layout:fixed ignores td width

Tags: css, html

I have a table which gets repopulated when the user sorts the columns. When the user clicks a column on the header, I remove all the rows except the `th` (header) and re-add the new rows. In my table I define the widths of the first row of the table (header). I also set the table to `table-layout:fixed;`. This makes all the columns proportional and ignores with column widths. If I remove the `table-layout:fixed;` the columns are the correct width but upon repopulating the table the widths changes and the header columns shifts. How I keep the column width fixed always?

```
<table id="CartProducts" class="Center" style="table-layout:fixed; width:1000px;">
    <tr class="DefaulTableHeader">
        <th style="width:120px" class="Left ">
            <div class="ProductSort" data-property="Sku" data-sort="ASC">Sku</div>
        </th>
        <th style="width:120px" class="Left ">
            <div class="ProductSort" data-property="MfgPartNumber" data-sort="ASC">MfgPn</div>
        </th>
        <th style="width:290px" class="Left ">
            <div class="ProductSort" data-property="Description" data-sort="ASC">Description</div>
        </th>
        <th style="width:80px" class="Right ">
            <div class="ProductSort" data-property="Msrp" data-sort="ASC">MSRP</div>
        </th>
        <th style="width:80px" class="Right ">
            <div class="ProductSort" data-property="Cost" data-sort="ASC">Cost</div>
        </th>
        <th style="width:80px" class="Right ">
            <div class="ProductSort" data-property="Price" data-sort="ASC">Price</div>
        </th>
        <th style="width:30px" class="Center ">
            <div class="ProductSort" data-property="Status" data-sort="ASC">Status</div>
        </th>
        <th style="width:100px" class="Center ">Add</th>
        <th style="width:100px" class="Center ">Custom</th>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Can't you set the columns externally via css, rather than inline based on nth-child?

Comment: Add that first row in `<thead>` element, and the rows you delete in `<tbody>`. And also, you didn't close your `<table>` element.

Comment: @Vucko that was a typo (fixed in OP) - I'll try your suggestion

Comment: @Chris I tried that. Same result

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but are you sure [table-layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) works the way you think? When I look at your table the column widths are exactly what you specify (plus the default cell-spacing, like Vucko said), but the table width is bigger than what you specify because of the [fixed table layout algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#propdef-table-layout)

Comment: @peterjb thx - if I change the `th` to `td`, the widths should match?

Comment: @PhillyNJ Sorry, it's not clear to me what you are looking for. Can you put more code or a screenshot?  As far as I know, `th` or `td` shouldn't matter.

Comment: @peterjb Thanks for the help. In a nut shell, I want the column widths to be fixed. Right now, it the column width is set to 100px, and the context is larger/smaller the columns shrink or grow.

Comment: I wrote up a test on jsfiddle, let me know how this compares to what you want to happen: jsfiddle.net/4r8fdf90

Comment: @peterjb thanks for the help. I was able to reproduce the issue in your jsfiddle. The issue was with 2 static rows that had a `colspan="9"`. Moving them out of the table, fixed the issue. Make this an answer and its yours. http://jsfiddle.net/7u5ooor1/1/